# How to have a file as schema for pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

So I have the following code:

My ultimate goal is to have the file produced be the schema for another input file. Is this possible? The output of the current script looks like this:

```
%declare INPUT '$input'
%declare SCHEMA '$schema'
%declare OUTPUT '$output'
%declare DEL '$del'
%declare COL ':'
%declare COM ','
A = LOAD '$SCHEMA' using PigStorage('$DEL') AS (field:chararray, dataType:chararray, flag:chararray, chars:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT(field,CONCAT('$COL',CONCAT(REPLACE(REPLACE(dataType, 'decimal','double'), 'string', 'chararray'),'$COM')));
rmf $OUTPUT
STORE B INTO '$OUTPUT';
```

Not sure the right approach.

Here is the output:

```
record_id:chararray,
offer_id:double,
decision_id:double,
offer_type_cd:integer,
promo_id:double,
pymt_method_type_cd:double,
cs_result_id:double,
cs_result_usage_type_cd:double,
rate_index_type_cd:double,
sub_product_id:double,
campaign_id:double,
market_cell_id:double,
assigned_offer_id:chararray,
accepted_offer_flag:chararray,
current_offer_flag:chararray,
offer_good_until_date:chararray,
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, You can use the `run` command of `pig` to run the script and do the stuff as needed by you, For more explanation of how to do, refer this [link](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/cmds.html)
Hope it helps!

Comment: My intention is to pipe the output I created into a format that I can use as an input in the same pig script for another file load.